# WPF DataGrid. Пропадает выделение строки

Tags: .net, wpf

Есть элемент `DataGrid`, в котором отображается некий список строк, которые может выделить пользователь. Суть проблемы заключается в том, что если пользователь выделил строку в гриде, а потом перешел на другой элемент управления (т.е. кликнул по нему или еще что-то сделал), то выделение со строки в гриде пропадает. Как сделать так, чтобы строка в гриде оставалась выделенной даже если пользователь перешел на другой элемент управления.

Код грида. Удалил из него лишнее. Вроде привязки, полей и т.п.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
         RowBackground="LightYellow">

 <DataGrid.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" 
         Color="MediumAquamarine"/>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static  SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"              
         Color="MediumAquamarine"/>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Дело скорое всего как я подозреваю связано с AlternatingRowBackground и RowBackground. И кроме того еще Visua Studio ругается на строку

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="MediumAquamarine"/>
```

Ошибка:

> The member "InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey" is not recognized or is not accessible

Comment: а у вас какая версия .NET?

Comment: .NET 4 версия. 4,5 нельзя использовать, т.к. нужно чтобы ПО под XP тоже работало.

Comment: тогда мои вам соболезнования. Данное свойство появилось лишь в 4.5

Comment: Получается в 4 версии придется оставить все как есть и никаких вариантов больше?

Comment: Разумеется нет. Обновил ответ

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле выделение не пропадает, оно меняет цвет, почти сливаясь с другими строками. В данном случае требуется лишь сменить цвет неактивной выделенной строки на что-нибудь поярче. Например:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="0">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="MediumAquamarine"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="MediumAquamarine"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Впрочем, это будет работать только на .NET 4.5 и выше.

Вот рабочий пример для .NET 4:

```
<DataGrid  Name="MyGrid" >
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumAquamarine" />                                                        
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Скопировал Ваш код, почему то выделение пропадает все равно.

Comment: Ну показывайте тогда код

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: @DreamChild спасибо большое, то что нужно. Теперь хоть визуально все видно )