# Как задать цвет выделения, когда элемент находится не в фокусе?

Tags: c#, wpf

Слева находится контрол в фокусе и его цвет ярко синий, а справа не в фокусе и он бледно-серый...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу поменять его стиль и поменять цвет так, чтобы он был всегда ярким как-будто элемент в фокусе? Пытался найти свойство, но не нашел...

Comment: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>` внутри ресурсов `DataGrid` или окна. Этот вопрос точно здесь разбирался много раз, но я не искал, некогда.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/352110/218063